# use State base verification or Behavior base verification?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking

In my oponion,I tend to like the state ,The reason are:
1.state base verification is more simple and easiler to understand.
2.State base verification use the "AAA" model.
3.Behavior base verification will affect the refactoring more than state base.
What do you think? Use one of them or both? Why?

Comment: too broad question, please speify some concrete axample of an application. As is it now, the both of them can be true, or false. No correct answer is possible.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for 'What kind of question not to ask here' (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). It is chatty, open-ended and could (possibly) take a book to answer - or at least a chapter or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, state-based testing yields more readable and maintanable tests and is easier to follow. Behavior-based verification has its applications of course, but I would say you should only resort to it when state-based is not available.

Naturally, *it is possible* to replace any behavior-based verification with state-based, but you always have to judge whether doing so is worth your time and money. Consider simple alert raising service:

```
public void RaiseAlert(string message)
{
    var alert = builder.CreateAlert();
    alert.IsSystemWide = true;
    alert.Content = CreateAlertContent(message);
    var receivers = GetAlertReceivers(alert);

    smsService.SendSmsAsync(alert.Content, receivers);
    emailService.SendEmailAsync(alert.Content, receivers);
}
```

It's easy to guess that one of unit tests for `RaiseAlert` method would have to verify that sms was sent. How would you do that using state verification? There's **no observable state change** here. You'll have to roll your own mock and set some bool field marking that method was called. Or use mocking framework and do behavior-based verification.

Wherever you can, use state-based verification as it will be easier to follow in majority of cases. For the more complex minority, it might be a good call for behavior-based verification.

---

On a side note, behavior verification also utilizes *AAA* approach. It's just that the last *A* (*assert*) is replaced with *verify*, yet it serves **exactly the same purpose**.

Comment: Good points! I agree with you. And for the "AAA" approach, yes,it is also possible on the behavior,but seems like the state is more clear.